# Save .docx file django for specific user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm creating a docx file with user input in django. For now when the submit button is clicked the download link generates and users can download the file. However I want to save the file in file store and create a template where the user can see all the docx files (or a hyperlink) that he has created in the past. "Somewhat like a database"

models.py

```
class Timetables(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             default=1, related_name='timetables_files', null=True)
    timetable_files = models.FileField(
        null=True, blank=True, upload_to='word_documents')
```

views.py

```
def school_view(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
        worddocument = docx.Document()
        documenttitle = worddocument.add_heading(
            school_name_view.title(), 0)
        file = io.BytesIO()
        worddocument.save(file)
        response = HttpResponse(
            content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
            officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename =quicktimetable.docx'
        worddocument.save(response)
        path = join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'word_documents',
                    'quicktimetable.
        file = open(path, 'w+b')
        return response

class TimetablesView(ListView):
    model = Timetables
    template_name = 'quickmain/timetables_list.html'
```

timetables_list.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
{% for f in files %}
{{ f.files.url }}
{% endfor %}
{% for  timetable_files in user.timetables_files.all %}
     <embed src = "{{timetable_files.timetable_files.url}}" target="__blank">
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
```

How can I save the files which are generated and show all the files related to that user on a different a template.
I have a FileField in my models.py but no idea how to make use of it. I got a suggestion to regenerate file whenever users ask for it but I have no idea about that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the relation between the file and user model. 
Example 
**in your model**

```
class DocxFile(models.Model):
 user = models.ForiegnKey(User)      #your user model name
 file = models.FileField('upload_to='/')
```

**then in your views**

```
from yourappname.models import DocxFile
    def docs_file(request):
    files = DocxFile.object.filter(user=request.user)
    return render('your template path', {'files':files})
```

**in your template**

```
{% for f in files%}

{{f.file.url}}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I have edited my answer and with my template I'm able to see the number of files should be present for particular user by uploading files from admin panel. I've added different number of files for different users and I can see some window but in the small window it shows 'page not found' because django changes the file name and I don't know what's happening there.
The only problem I actually have now is to save the docx file which I'm generating in file storage.

Comment: You can simple upload the file from the django admin. you have to define a media_url and media_root in your settings. and you can also upload it from the frontend of the application mate.

Comment: The docx file is generated from users input. I've tried using File and ContentFile and I'm not to able to find a way to save it for currently logged in user.

Comment: I found a way to save file with ```documentfile = Timetables() documentfile.timetable_files.name = path``` but it doesn't save it for current user, it saves it for the user with ```id``` ```1``` because the default value for user in foreign key in ```Timetables()``` model is 1.

Comment: thats because your are only saving file path also add this
``` documentfile.user = request.user ```